# How to set a local variable in Visual Studio Code launch.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I set a local variable in the `launch.json` file. i.e. if I set `var myvar = "myvar"` somewhere in my file, how would I reference `${myvar}`?

```
var myvar = "myvar"
{
    "thing_to_set": "${myvar}" // This does not work
    "version": "0.2.0"
}
```